# Javascript AG-Grid Fetching and Displaying Data

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am trying to display data from an AJAX call in AG Grid and no data is being displayed.  I can see my AJAX call is working as expected because the result contains the object List that I want to show, but no grid is even appearing.
Below is my code for Index.cshtml. Below that is my Inv.js and the result is the return from the AJAX call.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">
    <div id="Inventory" width="100%" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
```

```
        var columnDefs = [
            { headerName: "ID", field: "ID", sortable: true, filter: true },
            { headerName: "InvID", field: "InvID", sortable: true, filter: true },
            { headerName: "Number", field: "Number", sortable: true, filter: true }
        ];

        var gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs
        };

        var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#Inventory');
            new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="Inventory" style="width:100%; height:100%;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>`
I had to add a height attribute to my div and now the grid shows.